# Configure default-threading-profile on mule 3.4.1

Tags: mule, threadpool

I using mule studio with mule ee version 3.4.1. I try config with below details and using jmetter to test with 3threads(3 users) call in the same time

1. Case 1: poolExhaustedAction = WAIT, maxThreadsActive=1, maxBufferSize =0

**<default-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" 
            maxBufferSize="0"  poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />**

Then, I run jmetter with 3 threads: => all request return error:

ERROR 2015-06-29 10:37:06,920 [[threadingconfigure1].http.request.dispatch.8081.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: ThreadPoolExecutor did not accept within 30000 MILLISECONDS
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: ThreadPoolExecutor did not accept within 30000 MILLISECONDS
    at org.mule.util.concurrent.WaitPolicy.rejectedExecution(WaitPolicy.java:62)

...

2. Case 2: poolExhaustedAction = WAIT, maxThreadsActive=2, maxBufferSize =0

**<default-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="2" 
            maxBufferSize="0"  poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />**

I run jmetter with 3 threads: => all requests were processed.

INFO  2015-06-29 10:47:03,432 [[threadingconfigure1].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: UUID:bcad02b4-10c5-405a-8459-257f5e946b3c
INFO  2015-06-29 10:47:13,506 [[threadingconfigure1].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: UUID:1c988f5a-df07-4888-a689-61ed00d6b9c1
INFO  2015-06-29 10:47:23,521 [[threadingconfigure1].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: UUID:352ca9a2-0003-4336-aab7-fda9f27c035c

**[QUESSIONS]**

1. Case 1: Why didn't have any request was processed? Although I configure maxThreadsActive = 1
2. Case 2: Why only connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02 is running and processing for each request? How about connector.http.mule.default.receiver.01? What are tasks of connector.http.mule.default.receiver.01?

Any idea is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually `connector.http.mule.default.receiver.01` is reserved for polling. Do you have any polling inbound HTTP endpoint on this connector?

Comment: @DavidDossot : Thanks so much for your answer. On my flow, I using below config:  
`<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
   host="localhost"  port="8081" doc:name="HTTP">`  
  
you mean this is a "polling inbound HTTP endpoint" ?

Comment: It all depends on the HTTP connector configuration you use, not the endpoint.